# Inform brand new employer about another offer?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, compensation

So I just formally accepted a position with a new company (Company A). I haven't begun work with them yet. I informed another company that I was in talks with (Company B) that I had accepted the position. Company B hadn't made an offer yet, but decided to counter-offer once they learned of Company A's offer.

I feel like Company A is the better fit for me at this point, but Company B's compensation is a little bit better. Also, it doesn't seem right to re-open negotiations immediately after I formally accepted an offer. So all in all, I'm pretty committed to Company A.

My question is, should I at least inform Company A of the counter offer? Just to say "Hey, these guys are submitting a slightly better package." Any advice?

Comment: Be careful - might end up with no job offers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't "inform" them simply for the sake of being polite.**

If you do, the ***perception*** is going to be that you're asking for a counter-offer. I would normally say that it's a perfectly acceptable negotiation technique, however, you've ***already signed*** with them.

If you do decide to leave no one can stop you, but bringing up the money some other company is currently offering you is not going to gain you any sympathy.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, it doesn't seem right to re-open negotiations

Listen to that inner voice - it's correct.

You negotiated in good faith with Company A and accepted a position with them.

Since Company A seems a good fit, just let the compensation difference pass (unless it's huge, like double).

If you go back to Company A and say, "B just offered me x% more", you're going to appear petty - as if money is the only reason to be there.  You run the risk of A saying "we won't stop you - go with B - we rescind our offer / go away"

Answer (score 1):

As the other comments have said, it's best to not mention it to Company A.  You have already accepted a position, which is the end of negotiations.  Consider how you would react if, after having negotiated and both parties agreed, Company A then tried to renegotiate with you for a lower salary.

One thing I *would* do is reiterate to Company B that you have already accepted an offer and that you feel it would be in bad faith to accept a different position now.  However, also ask them if it is an open offer.  Remember that your probationary period with Company A (assuming there is one) is a two-way agreement - it also means you're judging whether you want to continue working for them.  If Company B extends an open offer and you feel Company A is not a good fit for you, you now have the ability to return to Company B and, assuming the offer is still on the table, sign with them.